# Firestore Pagination get next batch of data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I have this function which fetches documents from a collection. I got this logic form the Firestore documentation but I do not understand the purpose of `addSnapshotListener`.

In a real scenario I need to:

First run a first query, get the last document and pass it to the next query and so on right?
So this means that after each query I need to return also the last document?
If this is the case why do I need `addSnapshotListener`? I can get `lastSnapshot` also from `.getDocuments()`

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject, LoadProtocol {
    var firestoreService: FirestoreService = FirestoreService()
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    
    let first: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection("items").limit(to: 1)
    var next: Query = Firestore.firestore().collection("items").limit(to: 1)
    
    init() {
        self.first.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("Error retrieving cities: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
                // The collection is empty.
                return
            }

            // Construct a new query starting after this document,
            // retrieving the next 25 cities.
            self.next = self.firestoreService.db.collection("items")
                .start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)

            // Use the query for pagination.
 
        }
    }
    
    func refresh() {
        self.firestoreService.fetchCollection(query: self.next) { (result: Result<[Item], Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let items):
                self.items += items
                self.addToCategories()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing Basic Cursor Pagination with Query Cursor Pagination on your implementation.

The Basic Cursor Pagination Part of your code (up to the `first.addSnapshotListener`) is correct and will execute everytime returning more and more data to your map every time you call the function and resolve it, however the Query Cursor Pagination part will never be called, so you can remove that part completely from your implementation.

So your code should look like:

```
func fetchCollection<Collection: CollectionProtocol>(lastSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?, query: Query, completion: @escaping (Result<[Collection], Error>) -> Void) {
    var first = query.limit(to: 1)

    if let lastSnapshot = lastSnapshot {
        first = query.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)
    }

    first.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
            // print(snapshot.metadata.isFromCache)
            completion(.success(snapshot.documents.map { document -> Collection in
                return Collection(document: document)
            }))
        } else if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You might also add the `.limit(to:1)` to your lastSnapshot check, since the way it is now, it will retrieve all the documents, of course, if that is your intended logic, ignore this note.

---

EDIT:

If you want to use Query Cursor Pagination, you have can follow this example where the listener is located outside of the fetchCollection function and it's executed everytime a getDocuments() is triggered and mounts the new query to be executed:

```
//initial state of your app
var results = "nil";

//initial query
var query = db.collection("foo").document("bar").limit(to: 1);

//everytime you need more data fetched and on database updates to your snapshot this will be triggered
query.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { 
        // update data
    }
    let next = db.collection("foo").document("bar").start(afterDocument: result.last!).limit(to: 1);
    query = next;
};

//initial load of data
fetchCollection();

//simply executes the query
func fetchCollection() {
    query.getDocuments { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            if(result == "nil"){
                result = document.data().map();
            }else{
                result.map({ document.data() })
            }
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }

    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Keep in mind that this is a untested example but it might be a good starting point to what you need in your app, Also, I use this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) for the realtime updates on the listener, you might find some more information on that link.

Comment: Thats my current implementation but I was thinking to change it to Query Cursor Pagination but I'm not sure how.  So the first step is to listen to my snapshot and then execute the next query? This will not work for my first query but only for my next query, please see my updated question

Comment: In that case, you would have to return your listener. I will add it to the answer

Comment: and then where do I use the returned `listener`? When I call the function again? Can you please do a small ex on how to invoke it, im a little bit confused

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example of how to implement it with snapshotListener, sorry about the previous statement, I misunderstood the documentation, which is quite confusing for swift, but the current one should work.

Comment: How do i call it the 2nd , 3rd time? while the user is scrolling?

Comment: Yes, you should call the `fetchCollection()` function on every interaction that requires more data, the listener will simply mount the next query

Comment: The thing is that i'm using SwiftUI. I'm putting this logic in my viewmodel. could this be an issue? I do not have a view controller. I get the results the first time, when i hit refresh I get all the rest. I want just one more. so one by one. and also when I change a field in the the db it is not reflected in the ui

Comment: Please check my updated question to see my current implementation

Comment: I saw your updated code, and I don't think that this is an issue tbh, you can still make the same call to the `fetchCollection()` function when you hit your refresh button instead of an user reactive refresh, this is really up to you. The only thing I would add is that you should probably always assign the next query to the original one at the end of the listener, otherwise, if you execute `next`, the listener will not be triggered, since it is pointing only to the `first` query.

Comment: But to your point of only wanting one more call, I think you should actually use simple cursor pagination without listeners in that case. It would be enough to what appears to be your app's needs

Comment: The purpose of the addSnapshotListener is to listen for document changes also or just to update the query?

Comment: What i want to achieve is that. I load x documents the first time. then when the user pulls to refresh i want to load x more, BUT if somethting changes in the database in one of the documents which is already in the ui I want it to be updated.

Comment: I did it exactly as you wrote. but the first time I get one then I get everything. I need one more.not all the rest. smth is wrong with the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212863/discussion-between-ralemos-and-rexhin-hoxha).